# How to import a Amazon AWS's client javascript into my Ionic 2/Angular 2 app?

Tags: javascript, import, typescript, angular, ionic2

I'm developing an Angular 2/Ionic2 application which uses an custom client api generated by Amazon AWS.

This api consists of a javascript and its dependencies which are other javascripts.

Normally I would just put it into a script tag inside the html, but I'm using typescript.

In the main javascript there's an object declarated this way:

```
var apigClientFactory = {};
apigClientFactory.newClient = function (config) {
    var apigClient = { };
    if(config === undefined) {
        config = {
            accessKey: '',
            secretKey: '',
            sessionToken: '',
            region: '',
            apiKey: undefined,
            defaultContentType: 'application/json',
            defaultAcceptType: 'application/json'
        };
    }
...
```

In a service I need to call the api this way:

```
    var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient();

    var params = {
      limit: 5
    };


    var body = {

    }

    var additionalParams = {

    }

    var headers = {

    }



    var queryParams = {

    }

    apigClient.cadastroOptions (params, body, additionalParams).then(function(result){
        var json = JSON.parse(result.data);

        console.log('Result', json);

    }).catch('Sucesso', function(json){
        console.log('Falha: ', json)
    });
```

It's not an node module. It's an api downloaded in a zip.

How could I import this in my application?

Comment: I'm guessing you are using SystemJS to load your modules. Maybe have a look at how you can load a js file using system js? :)

Comment: I installed it via "ionic start ionic2-tutorial-github blank --v2 --ts". This command installs a starter pack and don't seems based on SystemJS. It seems based on Gulp.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install the [`aws-sdk` module from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) and it's typings.

1. `npm install aws-sdk --save`
2. `typings install dt~aws-sdk --save --global`

Actually using the lib in your project might vary, but angular-cli's guide on [importing 3rd party libs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs) might be helpful (specifically the last step of any given section) in showing how that's done.

Comment: I think the OP meant custom SDK for the API Gateway. It seems the only way to use it with Angular2/Typescript currently is to create type definitions by hand. Or generate an alternative SDK with swagger-codegen, though that would only work for public APIs.

Comment: @dinvlad your comment seems better suited as an answer since it offers better insight into the solution than mine does.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently, add the script tags into your index.html, then in your component add the following:

```
declare var apigClientFactory: any;

@Component({
selector: '<selector>',
templateUrl: './<html>',
styleUrls: ['<css>']
})

export class <your class> {
    constructor(){}
}
```

Be aware that if you are using webpack however this will not be added to the dependencies.